# Highlight code in HTML using <font color="#xxx">

Tags: html, highlight

I want to know how to highlight my code in HTML like this.

```html
<font color="#1773cc">#include </font><font color="#4a6f8b">&lt;NTL/ZZ.h&gt;</font><br>
<br>
<font color="#b02f60"><b>using</b></font>&nbsp;<font color="#008b00"><b>namespace</b></font>&nbsp;std;<br>
<font color="#b02f60"><b>using</b></font>&nbsp;<font color="#008b00"><b>namespace</b></font>&nbsp;NTL;<br>
<br>
<font color="#008b00"><b>int</b></font>&nbsp;main()<br>
{<br>
&nbsp;&nbsp; ZZ a, b, c; <br>
<br>
&nbsp;&nbsp; cin &gt;&gt; a; <br>
&nbsp;&nbsp; cin &gt;&gt; b; <br>
&nbsp;&nbsp; c = (a+<font color="#ff8b00">1</font>)*(b+<font color="#ff8b00">1</font>);<br>
&nbsp;&nbsp; cout &lt;&lt; c &lt;&lt; <font color="#4a6f8b">&quot;</font><font color="#8a2ae2">\n</font><font color="#4a6f8b">&quot;</font>;<br>
}<br>
```

> code from [here](https://libntl.org/doc/tour-ex1.html)

Just using `<font color="#xxxxxx">xxx<font>` to highlight code. 
Is there a tool to implement this, or I have to write it by hand?

I've tried some tools, like [Typora](https://support.typora.io/Quick-Start/) and [Vim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vim_%28text_editor%29), but that's not what I want.

I want to highlight code using `<font color="#xxxxxx">xxx<font>`.

Is there a tool to implement this, or do I have to write it by hand?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/font "Warning: Do not use this element."

Comment: Lots of existing libraries for this. https://highlightjs.org/ https://prismjs.com/ https://prettier.io/ etc.

Comment: Do you mean highlighting the code in your IDE or in your webpage? Could you please make clarity on this.

Comment: I'm mean highlighting my code in the html file using `<font color="#xxxxxx">xxx<font>`, and then view it in browser.

Comment: Note that the `<font>` element has been [obsolete](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/obsolete.html#obsolete) for 20 years or more. I would hope no editor would implement this.

Comment: There is [a site for recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To highlight your HTML code you have to use a library on your website. There you can find many libraries for this purpose but I think this is one of the best options you could have.

https://highlightjs.org/

Please visit the link and follow the instructions to include.

PS: I don't recommend writing it on your own.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement your own syntax highlighter, or use something that already exists. This is a CSS-only highlighter: https://www.cssscript.com/css-only-syntax-highlighter/

A preview from CSSScript:

[image]

Comment: @Rob this is a preview of how CSSScript looks alike. The content shared here is not the code itself, but the way the code looks alike if CSSScript is being used.